# Lin bus add a slave to a configured lin cluster

Tags: automation, protocols, microcontroller, can-bus

Hello I'm working on lin bus and i wanted to know if is it possible to autoaddress a slave that we add on a cluster already configured.

imagine a cluster with master and several slaves working (NAD assigned and LDF created) and we add a new slave is it possible to autoaddress or is there any probleme caused by the initial NAD.

Is there any way to detect a new slave added to a configured cluster ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you can control both master and slaves, you can implement simple scanning procedure. For example, master tries to scan all possible addresses. Configured (old) slaves answers to this requests. New unconfigured slave assigns itself free address (which have no answer from any other slave).

Of course, when user will add new slaves, he should check, that all "old" slaves works correctly. Otherwise "new" slave can take a place of temporary disconnected "old" slave.

Comment: Well first thanks for your answer.But how can the new slaves know about the free addresses ? And except using a daisy chain system i don't see how i can assign the NAD since the master doesn't know the initial NAD. any hint on that ?